# Distance between two layers along the road network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have four layers:

1. Crime
2. School
3. Census tract
4. Street

I want to calculate the distance between one school to each crime incident along with the road network. Moreover, Those school and crime incidents should be within one census tract. For example, the attached census tract has two schools **(Green color-A, B)**.

How can I calculate the distance between A to each crime within the particular census tract and B to each crime incident in that census tract along with the road network?

[image]

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I try to apply the "Closest Facility" tool. I do not know how to apply the search area.